# Searching tree by birth or death location

Tags: research-methods

In building my tree, I've found some very interesting groupings of families on both my paternal and maternal lines that intersect in specific areas at specific times.

How can I search my tree to find all relatives born or died in Isle of Wight, VA, for example?

It appears my "tree search" is limited to names. If I could export to excel, for example, it would be easy to search all fields.

I guess that's a related question - does anyone know a shortcut to exporting ancestry.com files to Excel?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What genealogy software/site are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You can export your Ancestry tree as a gedcom file. You could then import it into one of the many genealogy programs that are available, some free or some paid. Alternatively as you have mentioned Excel in your OP you could use GedXlate (free available from [here](http://www.gedmagic.com/gedxlate.htm)) to convert your downloaded gedcom file into an Excel file.